# Ajax within an each() method

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have three scripts

The first one dynamically generates a form that contain several inputs whose values contain the id_mensaje I'm intereted in. I want to delete the mysql registries related to the id_mensaje. 
I'd rather show you the scripts

1.- correo.php

```
<div id='eliminar_mensaje'><a href='#'>Eliminar</a> </div>      
<form>  
<input class='elim_msg' type='checkbox' value='id_mensaje_".$i."' />  

...  more inputs whith same class name

</form>
```

2.- correo.js

```
$('#eliminar_mensaje a').on('click', function(){  
    $('#loading').show();  
    $('.elim_msg').each(function(i,e){  
        var value = $(e).val();  
        var checked = $(e).prop('checked');  
        if(value != 'ok' && checked == true){  
            $.ajax({  
                url: 'private/control_correo.php',  
                type: 'POST',  
                data: 'id_mensaje='+value+'&accion=eliminar_mensaje'  
            });  
        } else {  
            //do nothing  
        }  
    });  
    location.reload(true);  
    return false;  
});
```

3.- control_correo.php

```
...} else if(isset($_POST['accion']) AND $_POST['accion'] == 'eliminar_mensaje'){  
        consultav2("DELETE FROM destinatarios WHERE id_mensaje = '".$_POST['id_mensaje']."';");    
        consultav2("DELETE FROM mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '".$_POST['id_mensaje']."';");  
    }
```

When you click on the link whithin the eliminar_mensaje div it looks that the javascript code works but it really doesn't for any reason i'm not able to find.

does any of you see anything in the scripts?
 Tanks a lot in advance!

Comment: you know that location.reload run at startup right?
You wanted that it will run after the ajax?

Comment: @Dvir no, I think it doesn't, its just a matter of wrong indentation

Comment: Hi Dvir. I want location.reload to run after the ajax. I didn't know the detail you mention. I guess I should remove it or try anything else to check whether it helps solve the issue.

Comment: Ok it's partial code so i can't see what at the top.
If it's executing after the ajax thats ok.
Try to put an alert to see if it's really work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need success and error parameters in your ajax call to determine whether the request was successful or not:

```
$.ajax({  
    url: 'private/control_correo.php',  
    type: 'POST',  
    data: 'id_mensaje='+value+'&accion=eliminar_mensaje',
    success: function(message) {
        // do things on success
        alert(message);
    },
    error: function(message) {
        // ajax request failed (not necessarily the server side processing failed)
        alert(message);
    }
});
```

You should also look at building an array of data to pass first, then passing in an array and just doing one ajax call.

```
$('#eliminar_mensaje a').on('click', function(){  
    $('#loading').show();  
    var ajaxArray = {};
    $('.elim_msg').each(function(i,e){  
        var value = $(e).val();  
        var checked = $(e).prop('checked');  
        if(value != 'ok' && checked == true){  
            ajaxArray.push( e ); // add contents of e to array 
        } else {  
            //do nothing  
        }  
    });

    // done with finding data, do ajax
    $.ajax({  
        url: 'private/control_correo.php',  
        type: 'POST',  
        data: {
            dataArray: ajaxArray
        },
        success: function(message) {
            // do things on success
            alert(message);
        },
        error: function(message) {
            // ajax request failed (not necessarily the server side processing failed)
            alert(message);
        }
    });
    // your server side script loops through the passed array and does things there, only one ajax request
});
```

Also, what's the location.reload() for? That happens on click as well and might be interfering with your ajax processing... if you send an array with ONE request, you can put your location.reload into the success function.

Comment: That's it! The solution was not looping the ajax request but creating an array inside the each method and after that making a unique ajax request. In the php page that receives the array I did a foreach statement with $_POST['dataArray'] and it worked perfectly! In the saccess function I put location.reload(true).

Answer (score 0):

`$.ajax` in `.each` means you're making a series of simultaneous AJAX requests and these are probably failing. You need to queue your AJAX request, so that only one at a time is active at any given point. The others need to wait in line. Alternatively, you can modify your server script to accept a single request containing multiple items.

Comment: Hi defrost, I suspected anything similar to what you say, but as I'm a newbie I have no idea how to queue the ajax requests. Could you give me a clue to start to investigate about it with?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
data: { id_mensaje: value, accion: 'eliminar_mensaje'}
```

instead of:

```
data: 'id_mensaje='+value+'&accion=eliminar_mensaje'
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine for you

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#eliminar_mensaje a').on('click', function(){  alert('hj')
    $('#loading').show();  
    $('.elim_msg').each(function(i,e){ 
        var value = $(e).val();  
        var checked = $(e).prop('checked');  
        if(value != 'ok' && checked == true){  
            $.ajax({  
                url: 'private/control_correo.php',  
                type: 'POST',  
                data: 'id_mensaje='+value+'&accion=eliminar_mensaje'  
            });  
        } else {  
            //do nothing  
        }  
});  

}); 

});

</script>



<input type="button" class="clik_for_fetch" value="dsfds"/>

<div id='eliminar_mensaje'><a href='javascript:void(0)'>Eliminar</a> </div>      
<form>  
<input class='elim_msg' type='checkbox' value='id_mensaje_".$i."' />  

...  more inputs whith same class name

</form>
```